# SQL with cte, how to concat data, not join

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have query

```
SELECT Site, Risk_Time_Stamp,COMPUTER_NAME, [IP_ADDR1_TEXT],Number_of_Risks
    FROM dbo.sem_computer
    WHERE [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
    GROUP BY Site, Risk_Time_Stamp,COMPUTER_NAME, [IP_ADDR1_TEXT],Number_of_Risks
```

which gives 4 rows of output

and another query

```
select * from SEPM_site
```

which gives 1000 rows of output

I wish to concat both outputs such that there are 1000 rows of output

However when I do

```
; with cte as (SELECT Site, Risk_Time_Stamp,COMPUTER_NAME, [IP_ADDR1_TEXT],Number_of_Risks
    FROM dbo.sem_computer
    WHERE [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
    GROUP BY Site, Risk_Time_Stamp,COMPUTER_NAME, [IP_ADDR1_TEXT],Number_of_Risks)
select *
from cte
join SEPM_Site ss
on cte.Site = ss.Site
```

I get 4 rows of output instead of 1000

How to fix this?

Comment: Are there more than 4 matching rows in the SEPM_site table?

Comment: @sam-cd No there is not, but for the remaining 996 non-matching rows, I would like it to output blanks, or n/a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting 1,000 rows because the JOIN doesn't have 1,000 matches. If you want to get all the rows, even when there's no match, use a LEFT JOIN starting on SEPM_Site table.

```
; with cte as (SELECT Site, Risk_Time_Stamp,COMPUTER_NAME, [IP_ADDR1_TEXT],Number_of_Risks
    FROM dbo.sem_computer
    WHERE [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
    GROUP BY Site, Risk_Time_Stamp,COMPUTER_NAME, [IP_ADDR1_TEXT],Number_of_Risks)
select *
from SEPM_Site ss
LEFT join cte
on cte.Site = ss.Site
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `left join`:

```
with cte (. . .)
select *
from SEPM_Site ss left join
     cte 
     on cte.Site = ss.Site
```

Note:  I reverse the order of the tables.  For your original query, you would want a `right join`.  I prefer `left join`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a [UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT ProductModelID, Name
FROM Production.ProductModel
WHERE ProductModelID NOT IN (3, 4)
UNION
SELECT ProductModelID, Name
FROM dbo.Gloves
ORDER BY Name;
GO
```

This will 'concat' your results from both queries so in the end you have 1004 records in result.